# How to bypass &quot; to inject XSS payload?

Tags: character-encoding, xss, urlencode

I am currently learning XSS attacks and I wondered - if in an `<input>` tag double quotes are replaced with `&quot;` then how to inject the payload.

For example

```
<input type="text" value="something">
```

But when I am trying to execute this payload `" onmouseover="alert(1)` then the final payload becomes like this below

```
<input type="text" value="&quot; onmouseover=&quot;alert(1)">
```

And when I checked the code it replace in this format

```
.replace(/"/g,"&quot;"))
```

That's why it's not executing my payload. Even I have tried with double encoding but it's not working

```
%2522 onmouseover=%2522alert(1)
```

Comment: See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65526/how-can-i-bypass-double-quotes-in-a-attribute-based-xss-attack

Comment: @cmbuckley Thanks let me check...

Comment: @cmbuckley i have gone through the Cheat_Sheet and tried with double encoding it's not working.....%2522 onmouseover=%2522alert(1)

Comment: If you correctly encode values, you shouldn’t be able to do XSS regardless of what values you throw at it. There are solutions to XSS if applied correctly. Otherwise XSS would be an unsolvable problem, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @deceze Hey thanks can you please recommend any encoding links because I have tried many but none are working..

Answer (score 1):

If you see `"` getting transformed to `&quot;` as it passes through the HTML, then that usually means that the application is doing output escaping properly. in general, that means the webapp is well-built.

Comment: ... or at the very least not susceptible to this particular attack vector.

Answer (score -1):

you use :
%2522 onmouseover=alert(1)

Instead of:
%2522 onmouseover=%2522alert(1)

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain more details, such that others can learn from it